# How do I make this button update a balance?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code and basically what I want to do is I want that on pressing the button the balance at the button is updated with the amount. If the balance is currently 15, and I add 10, I want it to add 10 to it.

```
from tkinter import *

def bal():
    ans = int (input1.get ())
    total = IntVar ()
    tot = int (total.get ())
    tot = tot + ans
    res.set(tot+ans)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")

upper = Frame(root)
upper.pack()

Label(upper, text ="Sum:", font = ('raleway', 15), ).grid(row=0, column = 0)
Label(root, text ="Balance:", font = ('raleway', 15)).place(rely=1.0, relx=0, x=0, y=0, anchor=SW)

res = StringVar()

input1 = Entry(upper)
num2 = Entry(root)

result = Label(root, textvariable = res,font = ('raleway',13))

result.place(rely=1.0, relx=0, x=80, y=-2, anchor=SW)

input1.grid(row=0,column=2)

Button(upper, text ="Add Funds", command = bal).grid(row=4, column=2, ipadx = 65)

mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to have a total that constantly updates in the function bal but it doesn't update for some reason. I am a python beginner, by the way :D
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `bal()` command function, all you need to do is retrieve the current input value and running total (balance), add them together, and then update the running total:

```
from tkinter import *

def bal():
    ans = input1.get()
    ans = int(ans) if ans else 0
    tot = int(res.get())
    tot = tot + ans
    res.set(tot)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")

upper = Frame(root)
upper.pack()

Label(upper, text="Sum:", font=('raleway', 15)).grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(root, text="Balance:", font=('raleway', 15)).place(rely=1.0, relx=0,
                                                         x=0, y=0, anchor=SW)
res = StringVar()
res.set(0)  # initialize to zero
input1 = Entry(upper)
result = Label(root, textvariable=res, font=('raleway', 13))
result.place(rely=1.0, relx=0, x=80, y=-2, anchor=SW)
input1.grid(row=0,column=2)
Button(upper, text="Add Funds", command=bal).grid(row=4, column=2, ipadx=65)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a new `IntVar` and you are using `.get` on this. Instead you want to be use get on `num2` to get the current number that is stored in there adding the input to this and updating the var.